# Error 401 Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I'm making a website with paypal system payment.

I made tests in sandbox mode, and everything was fine and worked perfectly, Then, I  changed the configuration to live mode, I changed the keys to live mode environment, and I changed the sdk_config.ini de mode=live and the apiContext to live mode.

When I want to make the payment, I get the login and start session paypal, Then when confirmed the payment, it returns a 401 error and show me this message:

**Paypal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException[401]: Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-022354.....**

I'm using php 1.5 REST API for a company in Mexico, and I do not know if the account has to have a service or a special setting to change from sandbox mode to live.

In addition, the error shows me as if I were working in sandbox mode that shows rather than just api.sandbox.paypal.com api.paypal.com

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That API doesn't work in Mexico yet, so I changed to a typical and traditional paypal class

Answer (score 1):

`401 - Unauthorized request` will be returned if your LIVE APP/Account does not have the elegibility on the specific payment feature. (REST API has limited country and currency support as of now, while Sandbox APPs are granted with full eligibility by default for testing purpose)

Check your account eligibility [HERE](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accountStatus), and see [Country/Currency Support List](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/)

Comment: I reviewed the country, and that says if supported, including currency